# javascript event bus architecture

Tags: javascript, architecture, event-bus

In [this video](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=zakas-architecture) at 20:50 ([corresponding slide](http://www.slideshare.net/nzakas/scalable-javascript-application-architecture/56)), Nicholas Zakas presents what I think is an Event Bus architecture. What I don't know is whether the calls that interact with the Bus should be asynchronous or not?
The second question: if the calls are asynchronous, how should they be implemented?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they are asynchronous indeed.

My guess is that way they seem to be implemented is by using `custom DOM events`.

This is a useful technique for decoupling in javascript and you can check jQuery's [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) docs, look for the 'custom' string to see how to fire a custom event.